# remove crumb from breadcrumbs

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, magento-1, breadcrumbs

is there any way remove specific crumb from breadcrumbs ?

we can add crumb method `addCrumb` from Block Class `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Breadcrumbs`

but I didn't find any method to remove crumbs like `removeCrumb` like method which remove crumbs from bread crumbs from any position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, the only way you can do that is via a block rewrite by creating a module so in `app/code/local/Vendor/Module/Block/Page/Html/Breadcrumbs.php`:

```
<?php

class Vendor_Module_Block_Page_Html_Breadcrumbs extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Breadcrumbs {

    public function removeCrumb($crumbName)
    {
        if (isset($this->_crumbs[$crumbName])) {
            unset($this->_crumbs[$crumbName]);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in `app/code/local/Vendor/Module/etc/config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vendor_Module>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Vendor_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <page>
                <rewrite>
                    <!-- Mage_Page_Block_Html_Breadcrumbs -->
                    <html_breadcrumbs>Vendor_Module_Block_Page_Html_Breadcrumbs</html_breadcrumbs>
                </rewrite>
            </page>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

And finally `app/etc/modules/Vendor_Module.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vendor_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Page />
            </depends>
        </Vendor_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Then you should be able to do the following in your layout XML file:

```
<reference name="breadcrumbs">
    <action method="removeCrumb">
        <crumbName>Home</crumbName>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Replace `Home` with whatever crumb name you need to remove.

NB: actually I'm pretty sure it could be possible to do it via an event observer on `controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before` I'm just not 100% sure how to tacle this one.

Comment: You can also use N98_LayoutHelper extenion, that includes this code. (see: https://github.com/netz98/N98_LayoutHelper)